# save_post only saves meta data on second save

Tags: save-post

I am trying to use the save_post hook, but it is not working as intended:
I want to save the Taxonomy (Region) with the ID 75 when the radio button 'wpcf-proprty_online' is 'y'.
When I open the Post & the 'wpcf-proprty_online' is first 'n' and then I change it to 'y' and hit save, it's not saving the region 75, only if I click a second time on save.

```
function save_online_shop($post_id) {

    if(get_post_meta($post_id, '', true)) {
        if(get_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-proprty_online', false)) {
            if(get_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-proprty_online', true) == 'y') 
            {
                    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, 75, 'region' );
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action('save_post_listing', 'save_online_shop', 999999);
```

I don't really get why this is happening, I also played around with the priority but couldn't get it working. 
I am using the save_post hook a similar way like that on another occasion, and am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the IF statements and use `save_post` hook instead of `save_post_listing` to see if an IF statement is blocking the `wp_set_post_terms`?

Also try `wp_set_object_terms` instead of `wp_set_post_terms`.

Furthermore, if you can make sure it has to do with the 
`if(get_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-proprty_online', true) == 'y')` statement, then this post_meta has not been updated before you are execusting this function. So why not update it within this function to make sure the value == 'n' or 'y'.

`update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-proprty_online', $_POST['the_name_of_yr_field'] );`